# Does "ptr=malloc(sizeof(char)*10)" use many times,one after another allocate pointer to same memory block or cause memory leak?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, malloc

Suppose I have the following piece of code in my program:

```
char *ptr;
ptr=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
ptr=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
ptr=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
ptr=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
```

Will a pointer to the same memory block be assigned to `ptr` each time,or a separate piece of memory be reserved each time and its pointer assigned to `ptr`,resulting in memory leak each time `malloc()` is called?

I am still learning C so bear with me if it's too basic.I tried googling but found no answer.

**EDIT::**

Thanks for your answers.Please tell me if this approach of me deals with the memory leak risk.My program simply asks for names of 5 people and displays it,without using static arrays.After reading your answers,I put the `free(ptr)` inside the loop,else before I had planned to use it only once outside the loop,after the loop.Am I correct now?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main ()
{
char *names[5],*ptr;
int i;

for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
    ptr=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    printf("Enter name no.%d : \n",i+1);
    scanf("%s",ptr);
    names[i]=malloc(strlen(ptr)+1);
    strcpy(names[i],ptr);
    free(ptr);


}
for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
printf("%s\n",names[i]);

}
```

Comment: short answer memory leak

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I didn't understand what you said.Can you make it a little clear?

Comment: @Thokchom He's rambling about details which don't matter for your question (and likely your next 50 questions).

Comment: Please check my edit and tell me if my approach to deal with memory leak using `free()` is correct.I had planned to **free** `ptr` outside the loop.

Comment: It's commonly pointed out in cases like these that `sizeof (char)` is always going to be 1, so you can just as well remove it. It adds nothing but clutter.

Comment: @Thokchom The ptr = malloc() should be outside the loop as it should only allocate a memory segment once. You can have it inside the loop but then you must `free(ptr)` at every lap in the loop. But please note that it doesn't make any sense to even use dynamic memory allocation for `ptr` in this case.

Comment: @Lundin Well,using dynamic memory for `ptr` does seem counter-intuitive in this case,but I was asked to write this program to overcome a drawback of using a static array--that every name  has to be of fixed size,resulting in unused bytes when names are smaller than the memory allocated to them.Allocating memory dynamically based on the input (using an intermediate buffer) seems to solve the problem.Can you please suggest a better approach?How else I can do it?

Comment: You are allocating `ptr` to a constant size, so it has the very same drawbacks that a static array has, plus it is far slower and more bug prone. `names` should be allocated dynamically, but the `ptr` variable should be allocated statically, with the size of the longest name allowed (worst case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`malloc()` will never return the same memory block multiple times, unless (of course) it has been `free()`'d since the last time it was returned. This is guaranteed by the C standard. Therefore, your code also leaks memory. Any memory allocator that handed out the same piece of memory twice would be worse than useless: Applications would step on their own toes, using the same piece of memory for different purposes, likely concurrently.

Edit: Barring buffer overflow issues, your code is correct in that it frees the 10-char buffers referenced via `ptr`. Calling `free(ptr)` just once, outside the loop, would indeed be incorrect. However, your code (as shown here) does not free the memory allocated later in the loop body stored in `names[i]`.

Comment: Actually, after `free(p); p = malloc(n)` the pointer `p` may be unchanged.

Comment: @larsmans True, that wording was misleading. I Edited, hopefully it's both correct and comprehensible.

Comment: @larsmans In `free(p)` we free the memory pointed by `p`.Why then the pointer `p` may be unchanged if we use `p=malloc(n)` thereafter?Isn't it guaranteed to point to the memory block allocated by the new call to `malloc()`?I am confused about it.please clarify.

Comment: @delnan Please see my edit and tell if I am correct there in my program's approach to deal with leak.

Comment: @Thokchom: since the memory block pointed to by `p` is `free`'d, it can be reused by subsequent calls to `malloc`; that's the whole point of `free`. I.e. you *can* get the exact same pointer back.

Comment: @larsmans Same pointer all right,but no memory leak risk at all eh?

Comment: @larsmans I had planned to use a `free(ptr)` only once after the loop,but after reading the answers,I put it in the loop.I did the right thing eh?No memory leak now?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, each `malloc` call will allocate a new block, which means that the previous one will be leaked.

EDIT: answer to the edited part of the question

You are now correctly releasing the blocks to which `ptr` points, however you are not releasing those allocated for `names`. You would also need:

```
for(i=0;i<=4;i++) {
   printf("%s\n",names[i]);
   free(names[i]);
}
```

In your case, you could skip using `ptr` and work on `names` directly. Here's an equally [un]safe version:

```
char *names[5];
int i;

for(i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
    names[i] = malloc(10);
    printf("Enter name no.%d : \n",i+1);
    scanf("%s",names[i]); // what if name is longer than 10 characters?
}

for(i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
   printf("%s\n",names[i]);
   free(names[i]);
}
```

However, operating system will reclaim the memory consumed by a process once the process exits, so in this simple example you don't have to worry, but I guess that this is only an illustration. I also assume that you don't care about user entering names longer than 10 characters which would write over the boundaries of allocated buffers.

Comment: Thanks.But please check my edit and tell me about what you think about that program.

Comment: How to take care of boundary then and not to over write the allocated memory? How can I make sure that it will not go more then 10chars?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314796/max-string-length-using-scanf-ansi-c

Answer (score 2):

A separate block of memory will be allocated each time, since C does not perform any garbage collection and no `free` calls are done in between the `malloc` calls. The first three blocks are leaked since you're not keeping pointers to them.

You can find out for yourself that the pointers are all distinct using a simple `printf` call:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ptr = malloc(10);     // no need for sizeof(char), it's 1 by definition
    printf("%p\n", ptr);
}
```

This should print four distinct numbers.

Comment: Please spare a moment to check the edit to my question as well.

Comment: @Thokchom: correction, misread your code. It seems safe except that you don't `free` before exiting (and you're also using more `malloc` calls than necessary; why copy from one `malloc`'d buffer to another?).

Comment: What else to `free` before exiting?Haven't I freed all memory blocks that `ptr` was ever associated with it in the program?Can you tell me what else to free?

Comment: Oh,I think I am getting you,I am not freeing the memory allocated to the names right..those who are pointed to by pointers in the array?If yes,will I need a loop to free those memory blocks pointed by each pointer in the pointer array?

Comment: @Thokchom: each `names[i]`. That doesn't matter much on most operating systems, but it's still good practice to match every `malloc` with one `free`. When in doubt, just count the number of calls to each in the program.

Comment: @Thokchom: you can `free` them in the `printf` loop. After the `printf`, they're no longer needed.

Comment: Is there any way to free all the memory blocks pointed by the pointers in the pointer array in **one go**?Or I need a loop for this?

Comment: @Thokchom: you need a loop. There's no standard shorthand.

Comment: Thanks.Last thing.Why you said `why copy one malloc'd buffer to another..`?Actually, my intent is to allocate just as much memory each time as there are characters in the names entered,which may vary.I have used `strlen`for this.Can you suggest a better approach where I won't need to copy.I really feel **copying** each time is an unnecessary overhead.But if I want to allocate only the `strlen+1` number of bytes,is there an alternative to copying?Tell me this only please.Last thing.If possible post the code snippet for it.

Comment: @Thokchom: you could use `realloc`. But be aware that most implementations of that don't actually shrink buffers unless they become much smaller than the initial allocation, and requesting ten bytes from `malloc` or `realloc` may actually use up (say) a hundred.

Comment: Thanks a lot.You have no idea how much i learnt from this discourse with you.

Answer (score 2):

This will cause a memory leak assuming each call is successful, all but the memory allocated to the last `malloc` will be inaccessible. You either need to keep a `pointer` to each block allocated by `malloc` or you need to `free` between successive calls. so yes, `malloc` will attempt to allocate distinct block of memory for each call. A quick test could be as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *ptr;
    ptr=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    printf("%p\n", ptr);
    ptr=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    printf("%p\n", ptr);
    ptr=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    printf("%p\n", ptr);
    ptr=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    printf("%p\n", ptr);
}
```

This will print out the address allocated each time. If you added a `free` between each call to `malloc` you may end up with the same `pointer`, a quick [test](http://ideone.com/cNbilf)  demonstrated this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your second part is right: it's a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

A new block of memory is allocated each time you call malloc.  This will create a memory leak as you have no way to reference the first three allocations to free them.

Answer (score 1):

You can check memory leaks by using valgrind,its very useful in detecting memory leaks.

```
valgrind ./progr
```

Comment: You have released the blocks to which ptr points but not the blocks which have been allocated for name